# Selenium Web Scraping C# Trying To Return A value

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to return the date and time value from the field named Bidding Ends:
I have tried other combinations of code but dont seem to be able to figure it out

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace WebScraperDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bidrl.com/auction/autotool-auction-1525-c-street-marysville-ca-september-19th-134834/item/wheel-cover-17686623/");

            //this line works
            String text1 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[ng-bind-html='item.title']")).Text;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text1);

            //dont work
            String text2 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li[ng-if='item.end_time']")).Text;
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text2);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are facing?you are not giving full picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li[ng-if='item.end_time']
```

Above CSS Selector is incorrect, it is not locating any element on the page.

If below is what you want to extract?

[image]

Then try the below code:

```
String text2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//b[text()='Bidding Ends:']//following-sibling::div")).Text;
```